# WPF canvas drawing with Graphics

Tags: wpf, drawing, canvas

1. I'd like to ask if there is any possibility to **draw on WPF Canvas** with some kind of a Graphics type providing methods like: `DrawLine, DrawPath` etc.. (as it was in .NET 2).

I know there's a lot of stuff like storyboards etc.. but I'm planning to do all the drawing in code behind and **to have just 1 Canvas in WPF without any child elements**.

2. Do you think it is a good idea? will it be smooth ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'd like to ask if there is any possibility to draw on WPF Canvas with some kind of a Graphics type providing methods like: DrawLine, DrawPath etc.. (as it was in .NET 2).

Yes, you need to use the [`DrawingContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.aspx) class

> Do you think it is a good idea? will it be smooth ?

That's hard to tell, depending on your exact needs... If the canvas doesn't have any child items, I think a better solution would be to create a custom control and override the `OnRender` method. Regarding smoothness, it all depends on how you implement it...