# Drawing primitives in WPF is extremely slow. How to improve?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing a CAD-like application which needs to display maybe tens of thousands of lines when stuff is zoomed out.

At the moment I use C++ and Direct2D, which works quite smoothly: I can draw 100000 lines in something like 16 milliseconds. So I know my (average) machine can handle that.

I'm trying to move to WPF but I'm finding the performance disappointing. With the code below the redraw takes nearly one second (when I resize the window for example).

Profiling says the bottleneck is somewhere in [wpfgfx_v0400.dll], but I can't see exactly which functions.

So my questions: What am I doing wrong? How can I improve the performance of the code below?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        var gg = new GeometryGroup ();

        Random random = new Random ();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            Point p0 = new Point (random.Next (1000), random.Next (1000));
            Point p1 = new Point (random.Next (1000), random.Next (1000));
            var lineGeometry = new LineGeometry (p0, p1);

            gg.Children.Add (lineGeometry);
        }

        var stroke = new SolidColorBrush (Colors.Red);

        gg.Freeze ();
        stroke.Freeze ();

        this.Content = new Path () { Data = gg, Stroke = stroke };
    }
}
```

Comment: *"How can I improve the performance of the code below?"* do not use WPF

Comment: Did you check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16107877/21727)?

Comment: I'm considering doing that, but I thought maybe I'm doing something very wrong in my test, cause I can't imagine Microsoft writing a framework which can't handle the drawing of 1000 lines.

Comment: mbeckish, if I do my drawing in OnRender(), that drawing gets covered by any Background I set. (And I need to set a Background or else I'm not getting mouse events, among other problems.)

Not that it makes much difference anyway. I had tried doing the drawing there too. I just happened to post the code that does the drawing using Geometries.

Comment: I don't think the slowness is from the line drawing. I think its because you are calling the Random.Next method a 1000 times. Random.Next is slow. Instead, try pre-filling a 1000 element array with random numbers, then generate your points from the array in the loop.

Comment: icemanind, note that i'm already "pre-filling". The code I posted belongs to a constructor, which only ever gets called once.

Comment: I tried your code, but in the `OnRender()` method of a custom `FrameworkElement` and it works ok. Response time is immediate with 1000 lines. I'll try with 200,000.

Comment: Nope, I tried 200,000 and the Window is completely unusable...

Answer (score 2):

Drawing things in WPF is slower than you'd expect! A line with 1000 points shouldn't be a problem in general, but I wouldn't hope to draw anywhere near 100000 points using WPF geometry primitives - instead you'll eventually have to drop down to either rasterizing yourself or using some raw DirectX embedded in your WPF application.

Specifically the case of a single line of 1000 points should be well within the bounds of reason, some thoughts:

- With random data, if the line goes back and forth to cover a lot of area, this can lead to some very ugly performance. This is not simply a case of creating a large area to redraw - going back and forth seems to cause some bad situation with WPF geometries
- If you're drawing a single line, try using a `PolyLine` or `PolyLineSegment` in your `Path`
- If you do actually want a number of disconnected lines, rather than a `GeometryGroup` full of `LineGeometry`, use a `Path` with many `PathFigure`s.

For the general case as other answers have pointed out, you can look into `OnRender` or `DrawingVisual` type approaches, depending what you're doing the performance may or may not be better. I think you'll still struggle with the amount of elements you're suggesting, unless you can do some kind of virtualization.