# alternative for picturebox.creategraphics in wpf?

Tags: wpf, winforms, c#-4.0

i want to display image in wpf application, that image will be drawn as graph based on the data entered by the user....when the suer clicks the submit button after entering the data the image(graph) should be displayed on the form..i did the same in my winform app using the code pasted below

```
string mData = txtmData.Text;
Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
Brush br = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
g.DrawString("*" + mData + "*", mFont, br, 50, 50);
```

in WPF i don't fine alternative for pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

Comment: [How to draw on a Window in WPF (best practice)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585990/how-to-draw-on-a-window-in-wpf-best-practice) maybe that will be helpful for you

Comment: You may take a look at the example in [RenderTargetBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx).

Comment: You really shouldn't draw on a picturebox like that in winforms either...